# How to properly format django settings.py?

Tags: database, django

I'm a django beginner and am reading "Practical django Projects". The book instructs to insert the following-

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = ‘sqlite3′
```

However, in the settings.py file DATABASES is instead a dictionary-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Is it a different version or am I mistaken? Also please suggest any tutorials online that you think will help me learn django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is for Django <=1.1, in 1.2 they changed the format of the database settings in order to allow for *all new* multiple databases. If your tutorial is telling you to create something like this:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
DATABASE_NAME = '/path/to/your/dev.db'
```

Then this is what you will need in order to implement an `sqlite3` database in the 1.2 syntax:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/path/to/your/dev.db',
    }
}
```

As always see the [Django documentation on the matter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) for more information, and for proof of my statement that this was around in version 1.1, have a look at the [docs from that version](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/settings/#database-engine).

Comment: Thanks! certainly will consult the documentation next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a different version. From 1.2 and onwards convention for specifying database parameters has been changed to provide multi-database support(although the previous conventions should also work, to preserve backward compatibility). You should look at the [official Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/). It's up-to-date and quite wholesome.